# How do I add a new administrator to CiviCRM?

Tags: permissions, user-account

How do I give a person admin rights to civi?

Comment: CiviCRM gets its permissions from your CMS (that is, Drupal, WordPress, Joomla or Backdrop), so without specifying your CMS it's hard to give more details.  Please specify your CMS and someone can answer your question!  Also, are you looking to add a new user?  Or grant an existing user administrative permissions?

Answer (score 2):

As JonG mentioned, it depends on your CMS. I use Drupal so in my case I either add a Drupal role I created called 'civicrm_administrator' to the user or I create a specific new role and tick the permission 'administer CiviCRM'